# Print array in pendulum arrangement in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am supposed to print the array in the pendulum arrangement. For some output, my answer is right but for some its wrong. why is it so?

```
test_case = int(input())
for i in range(0, test_case):
    n = int(input())
    arr = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    arr.sort()
    arr1 = [0] * n
    mid = int((n - 1) / 2)
    arr1[mid] = arr[0]
    i = 1
    j = 1
    for i in range(1, mid + 1):
        arr1[mid + i] = arr[j]
        j += 1
        arr1[mid - i] = arr[j]
        j += 1
    if (int(n % 2) == 0):
        arr1[mid + i] = arr[j]

    print(' '.join(map(str, arr1)))
```

Here I have tried for 2 test cases. For the 1st test case my output is right but for the 2nd test case, an array with size 8 my output is wrong.

```
2 #no. of test cases
5 # size of 1st array
4 1 3 2 5 #1st Input
5 3 1 2 4 # correct output
8  #size of 2nd array
539 161 985 856 166 29 726 590 #2nd input
856 590 166 29 161 539 985 0  # Wrong output
```

the expected output for the 2nd test case is :

```
856 590 166 29 161 539 726 985
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Are you looking for a better solution, as in the current answer? Or do you actually want to know what is wrong with your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not just this:

```
lst = [539, 161, 985, 856, 166, 29, 726, 590]

def pendulum(lst):
    srt = sorted(lst)
    return list(reversed(srt[0::2])) + srt[1::2]

ret = pendulum(lst)
# [856, 590, 166, 29, 161, 539, 726, 985]
```

sort the list then take every other element and assemble that to the new list.

note that the function accepts lists and returns a list; you may need to split your string into a list first (`lst = [int(i) for i in input().split()]`) and you may want to convert the result at the end: `strg = ' '.join(str(i) for i in ret)`.

---

in your code if `n = 8` you will get `mid = 3`; `i` will range from `1` to `3` and therefore `mid+1 <= 6`; you will never set `arr1[7]` - the last entry in your array will remain `0` if you input length is even.

Comment: thank you for the solution. But it would be very helpful if you could tell me what is wrong with the given code?

Answer (score 1):

```
test_case = int(input())
for i in range(0, test_case):
    n = int(input())
    arr = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    arr.sort()
    arr1 = [0] * n
    mid = int((n - 1) / 2)
    arr1[mid] = arr[0]
    i = 1
    j = 1
    for i in range(1, mid+1):
        arr1[mid + i] = arr[j]
        j += 1
        arr1[mid - i] = arr[j]
        j += 1
    if (int(n % 2) == 0):
        arr1[mid + i + 1] = arr[j]

    print(' '.join(map(str, arr1)))
```

---

modified your code. it works

The code you've written will add the last element at the "mid+i" position
here

```
 middle = (len(arr)-1)/2
```

`i =` (which iterates from 1 to mid+1 position) will also be same as `mid = (len(arr)-1)/2`

for even length of array assume `[5,4,3,1,2,6]`

```
mid = 2
i = 2
mid+i = 4
```

`arr[mid+i] =` last but one position

so for even length of array just add `+1` to the index position which will give you last position.

Answer (score 1):

```
t=int(input())
for x in range(t):
    l=list(map(int,input().split()))
    l.sort()
    n=len(l)
    j=[None]*n
    c=1
    if(n%2!=0):
        c=1
        d=1
        z=(n//2)
        j[z]=l[0]
        for k in range(2,n+1,2):
            j[z-d]=l[k]
            d+=1
        for k in range(1,n,2):
            j[z+c]=l[k]
            c+=1
    else:
        c=1
        d=1
        z=((n//2)-1)
        j[z]=l[0]
        for k in range(2,n,2):
            j[z-d]=l[k]
            d+=1
        for k in range(1,n,2):
            j[z+c]=l[k]
            c+=1
    print(j)
```

Comment: please add some details to your answer to explain how your code solves the problem. This will help others